# Why ist sc = SparkContext(conf = conf) not working

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

import initspark `

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("SimpleExample").setMaster("local")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

I am coding on mac [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFBZA.png)

Comment: First, please reformat the code sample. There are a few python syntax errors. Second, the image seems to tell you that there is no spark-submit. Find out where is your spark-submit. Also you can run pyspark script without spark-submit if you have pyspark package installed. Just run as python your_py_script.py(for testing).

Comment: how are you launching the commands? Are you launching a whole script or using the command line interactive interface?